# Python Programming - input/output

Tags: python, file, text

I am new to Python and need some help with my program. My quesiton has now been answered, thank you to everyone who helped me!

Comment: Have you thought about using a different file format? Just store using pickle, JSON, xml, etc etc etc. It does not need to be so complicated! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to parse a text file yourself, I would suggest you use one of the ready-made tools from the python standard library to do the work for you. There are several different possibilities, including [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#module-configparser), [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv), and [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html). But for my example, I will use [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

The `json` module allows you to save python objects to a text-file. Since you want to search for recipes by name, it would be a good idea to create a dict of recipes and then save that to a file.

Each recipe will also be a dict, and will be stored in the recipes database by name. So to start with, your `input_func` needs to return a recipe dict, like this:

```
def input_func(): #defines the input_function function
    ...
    return {
        'name': name,
        'people': people,
        'ingredients': ingredients,
        'quantity': quantity,
        'units': units,
        'num_ing': num_ing,
        }
```

Now we need a couple of simple functions for opening and saving the recipes database:

```
def open_recipes(path):
    try:
        with open(path) as stream:
            return json.loads(stream.read())
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # start a new database
        return {}

def save_recipes(path, recipes):
    with open(path, 'w') as stream:
        stream.write(json.dumps(recipes, indent=2))
```

And that's it! We can now put it all to work:

```
# open the recipe database
recipes = open_recipes('recipes.json')

# start a new recipe
recipe = input_func()

name = recipe['name']

# check if the recipe already exists
if name not in recipes:
    # store the recipe in the database
    recipes[name] = recipe
    # save the database
    save_recipes('recipes.json', recipes)
else:
    print('ERROR: recipe already exists:', name)
    # rename recipe...

...

# find an existing recipe 
search_name = str(input("What is the name of the recipe you wish to retrieve?"))

if search_name in recipes:
    # fetch the recipe from the database
    recipe = recipes[search_name]
    # display the recipe...
else:
    print('ERROR: could not find recipe:', search_name)
```

I have obviously left some important features for you to work out (like how to display the recipe, how to rename/edit recipes, etc).

Comment: @Will. That's probably because you didn't open the recipes database first. You need to do `recipes = open_recipes('recipes.json')` before trying to do a search (see my example code).